# Change Create button text for kendo grid with globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, globalization

I want to know if there is a way to change the text of the create button of a kendo grid with the system of globalization.
I'm using kendo.culture("fr-FR) on my layout and i'm importing the messages and cultures in the main.js. The messages of the kendo grid are in the good language but the button are not.

What i'm missing ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your tags, it appears as if you are using ASP.NET Core.

If that is the case, then take a look at this example: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/globalization?culture=fr-FR

Comment: yes i' using asp.net core. I already saw this example before asking and the only difference is just that i have no dropdown and i'm not putting the culture on the url. But by reading all the info i see that maybe the resource does not exist and that' why i see this in english. Idk if there is somewhere we can see all the french resource ?

Comment: @JeanTurin - All the dropdown does is allow you to select the culture. According to the documentation linked: The kendo.culture() method is used to set the client cluture to force the grid to use the matching date, number, currency, week and month formats.